# Show that if $x ≡ 1 (\text{mod } λ)$, then $x^3 ≡ 1 (\text{mod } λ^3)$...

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

Let $λ = (3 + \sqrt{−3})/2 ∈ Q[\sqrt{−3}]$. How do I show that if $x ≡ 1 (\text{mod } λ)$, then $x^3 ≡ 1 (\text{mod } λ^3)$. Also, how do I show that if $x ≡ −1(\text{mod } λ)$, then $x^3 ≡ −1 (\text{mod } λ^3)$, and that if $x ≡ 0 (\text{mod } λ)$, then $x^3 ≡ 0 (\text{mod } λ^3)$.

Comment: I have a question, is it possible to define 'mod' for real numbers?

Comment: @Ebearr: Sorry my bad. (Referring to deleted answer) I guess it seemed a little too simple. Haha. Should of thought of that.

Comment: @Bair No worries. Easy to miss.

Comment: This http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1250226/233398 helps. As there is only one congruence class in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$

Comment: @HyoyoungJung Mod is defined for algebraic integers: $\alpha\equiv \beta \pmod{\gamma}$ if there exists an algebraic integer $\delta$ with $\alpha-\beta = \delta \gamma$.  When $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are integers, this is equivalent to the usual definition.

Comment: @Slade Do you know how I can prove these three statements?

Comment: @Rachel Besides deleting one of your two identical questions, you should also post some context for the question, as well as steps you've taken to solve it.  The last of your statements can be proven trivially from the definitions, so you might give some indication of why you have been unable to prove it yourself.  The others are less trivial, but you should start with the easiest one first.

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS-** (for first assertion.)

1. $x^3-1= (x-1)(x^2+x+1)=(x-1)[(x-1)^2-3x]$, and as $x ≡ 1 (\text{mod } λ)$ you can let $x-1=\lambda t$ for some $t$ in $Q[\sqrt{−3}]$.
2. **Edit**

$\hspace{1cm}$ $\lambda^2=\frac{3(1+\sqrt{-3})}{2}$  divides $3$ in $Q[\sqrt{−3}]$. So you can let $3=\lambda^2t_1$  for some $t_1 \in Q[\sqrt{−3}]$

**MORE HINT-**

$x^3-1= (x-1)(x^2+x+1)=(x-1)[(x-1)^2-3x]=\lambda t(\lambda^2t^2-3x)=\lambda t(\lambda^2t^2-3(\lambda t+1))=\lambda^3 t^3-3\lambda^2 t^2-3\lambda t$.

Now use point 2 above and see that $\lambda^3$ divides RHS of above equation and thus $\lambda^3\ |\ x^3-1$

Comment: I've been looking into what you said, but I can't seem to figure it out. I don't know if I'm missing something, but I can't figure this out still.

Comment: apologies, some things were wrong, I have edited now. Now it will be clear

Comment: now it is perfect. Had to do one more edit